# What does the TextureRegion.flip() method do?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm learning libgdx and don't understand the purpose of parameters passed to `flip(boolean x, boolean y)`. For example, I have code like this:

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 20, 20);
textureRegion.flip(false, false);
```

My `TextureRegion` is flipped when both parameters are `true` and not flipped when they are `false`. But why does it need two parameters when it could have only one? The documentation says nothing about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

textureRegion.flip(false, false);
this will keep the original image as it is.

[image: sample]

textureRegion.flip(true,false) 
it will mirror the image as below.ie it will flip the original image horizontally and preserve its y direction.
[image]

textureRegion.flip(false,true) ;
 it will flip the original image vertically and preserve its x direction

[image]

textureRegion.flip(ture,true) ;
 it will flip the original image vertically and horizontally
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The parameters control which axis the image will be flipped around; sometimes you only want to flip around one or the other axis, instead of both.

The first parameter, if true, causes the image to be flipped in the X direction (horizontal flip) The second parameter, if true, causes the image to be flipped in the Y direction (vertical flip).

If both are true, the image is flipped around both axes.